# Showing related entities on MVC 4 partial view using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on asp.net MVC 4 application. I have a view model like this:

```
  public class MainViewModel
    {
        public List<EmailAccount> EmailAccounts { get; set; }
        public List<UserContact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public List<LinkedInProfile> LinkedInProfiles { get; set; } 

        public IConfig Config { get; set; }
    }
```

Contacts  and LinkedInProfiles  have many to many relationship so I have defined junction table:

```
 public class LinkedInAccountConnection
    {
       [Key]
       [Column(Order = 0)]
       public Guid LinkedInAccountId { get; set; }
       [Key]
       [Column(Order = 1)]
       public string LinkedInProfileId { get; set; }
     }
```

In view I am using this:

```
@foreach (var c in Model.Collection.Contacts.OrderByDescending(c => c.LastUpdated).Take(500))
    {
        @Html.Action("ContactListWidget", "Account", new { contact = c })
    }
```

EF code

```
var user = dataRepository.GetUserByUsername(username);
Contacts = dataRepository.GetContactsAll(user.Item.UserID).Where(c => c.UserContactEmailAddresses.All(e=> !Cleansing.IsAutomatedEmailAddress(e.EmailAddress))).ToList();

foreach (var c in Contacts)
{
    var userContactToLinkedInProfiles = c.UserContactToLinkedInProfiles;

    foreach (var uc in userContactToLinkedInProfiles)
    {
        var profile = uc.LinkedInProfile;
        LinkedInProfiles.Add(profile);
    }
}
```

I want to show information in ContactListWidget partial view related to contact  as well as related LinkedInProfile. What changes do I need to make to Viewmodel and view ?

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you put your EF query also ?

Comment: @Sampath added EF code.

Comment: I always load partial views through an ajax call.  see the question and answer here for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768352/how-to-bind-a-webgrid-in-a-partialview-which-is-in-jqueryui-modalpopup/21769106#21769106

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fill the ViewModel and then bind it to your view.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetDetails()
{

       var mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();

        mainViewModel.EmailAccounts=Repository.GetEmailAccounts();
        mainViewModel.Contacts=Repository.GetUserAccounts();
        mainViewModel.LinkedInProfiles=Repository.GetLinkedInProfiles(); 
        mainViewModel.Config=Repository.GetConfigData();

     return PartialView("ContactListWidget", mainViewModel );
}
```

**View**

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.MainViewModel  //set your viewmodel here
```

After that you can use that ViewModel's list data for bind to your other html elements.

**Performance Alert:** `@foreach (var c in Model.Collection.Contacts.OrderByDescending(c => c.LastUpdated).Take(500))`

- Please don't bring all the data into view and then filter inside the
  view.Just bring the filtered data only (i.e. filter inside the
  repository).It'll help to improve the performance of the view.